# "net-position" of a node in directed Erdos-Renyi graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

In a directed weighted random Erdos-Renyi graph $G(N,p)$ with only positive weights, let $e_{ij}$ denote the weight going from node $i$ to node $j$ and assume all $e_{ij}$'s are normally distributed. How can one calculate the expected value of the "net-position" of a node $i$?

i.e. is there a simple way to get the expected value of $\sum_{j=1}^n(e_{ij}-e_{ji})$?

or even better, to get the expected value of **all** the **positive** net-positions in the graph?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you call the net position is just a linear combination of (hopefully) iid normals.

Comment: @BobKrueger Yes, exactly. I am just confused, since the expected value of the sum of all weights of all incident edges from a node $i$ is $\frac{\mu (n−1)p}{2}$, where $\mu$ is the mean of the $e_{ij}$'s. But then by linearity and as they are iid the expected value of the net-position would always be zero? Or what I am missing?

Comment: It would seem that the expected net-position is zero. This makes sense because of all the symmetry: the expected value of $e_i-e_j$ is zero.

Comment: @BobKrueger Well, then thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome! I've made that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $e_{ij}$ are identical and independent normal distributions, any linear combination will also be normally distributed. Since then the expected value of $e_{ij} - e_{ji}$ is zero, the expected value of the "net-position" is always $0$.